# css for parent selector for attribute

Tags: css

I want to hide parent element `<li>` according to its child attributes:

This question is not solving my issue: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

My HTML:

```
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item">
    <a href="/modules/chk/" data-identity="extensionButton_9_2" class="tool-block">
        <span class="tool-icon">
            <img src="/modules/chk/images/button.png" alt=""></span>
        <span class="tool-name">Modules name</span>
    </a>
    <span class="tooltipData">Modules details</span>
</li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
```

Want to hide parent according to : `data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"`

My CSS:

Working for attribute:

```
[data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"]{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Not working css for parent:

```
[data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"]:parent {
    display: none !important;
}

li:has(> [data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"]) {
display: none !important;    
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: @04FS no, i am want to according attributes. so its not duplicate

Comment: It does not matter what you want to do it based _on_, selecting “upwards” in CSS is not possible in general.

Comment: @04FS not working according to that, if you know then post answer : li:has(> [data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"]) {
display: none !important;    
}

Comment: The answer to that question gives you some insight into the `:has()` selector, which is not yet implemented for stylesheets, but more detail can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: the other question will not solve your issue. It will tell you that you issue cannot be solved with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:has()` pseudo selector although browser support is [limited](https://caniuse.com/?search=has). Until this is resolved, you could use a [polyfill](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has).

```css
li:has(a[data-identity="extensionButton_9_2"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item">
  <a href="/modules/chk/" data-identity="extensionButton_9_2" class="tool-block">
    <span class="tool-icon">
            <img src="/modules/chk/images/button.png" alt=""></span>
    <span class="tool-name">Modules name</span>
  </a>
  <span class="tooltipData">Modules details</span>
</li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
<li class="tools-item"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the solution does not require a parent selector, because all the content in the offending `li` can be hidden with CSS, and then the `li` will collapse (as long as you don't use the regular list-style-type).

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  content: '\2022';
}

[data-identity='extensionButton_9_2'],
[data-identity='extensionButton_9_2']~* {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tools-item">one</li>
  <li class="tools-item">two</li>
  <li class="tools-item">
    <a href="/modules/chk/" data-identity="extensionButton_9_2" class="tool-block">
      <span class="tool-icon">
        <img src="/modules/chk/images/button.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="tool-name">Modules name</span>
    </a>
    <span class="tooltipData">Modules details</span>
  </li>
  <li class="tools-item">four</li>
  <li class="tools-item">five</li>
</ul>
```

Of course if the situation were more complex (e.g. if there was content in the `li` before the `a`), then it would have become more difficult to find a css-only solution!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, I wouldn't know what to say under there that hasn't been said already. I'm aware of the whole "when is a duplicate not a duplicate" situation, but I do not have a satisfactory answer.